# What does this 'would' mean?

Tags: modal-verbs

> "I don't know, sir," said Harry. 
>    Snape's lips curled into a
>   sneer. 
>    "Tut, tut -- fame clearly isn't everything." 
>    He
>   ignored Hermione's hand. 
>    "Let's try again. Potter, where would
>   you look if I told you to find me a bezoar?" 
>    Hermione
>   stretched her hand as high into the air as it would go without her
>   leaving her seat, but Harry didn't have the faintest idea what a
>   bezoar was. He tried not to look at Malfoy, Crabbe, and Goyle, who
>   were shaking with laughter. 
>     "I don't know, sir."
>   "Thought you **wouldn't** open a book before coming, eh, Potter?"
>   Harry forced himself to keep looking straight into those cold eyes. He
>   had looked through his books at the Dursleys', but did Snape expect
>   him to remember everything in One Thousand Magical Herbs and Fungi?
>   
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

It seems ‘would’ mean Potter’s will to read, not for the future possibility. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's equivalent to *"You thought you wouldn't **bother to read any books** before coming"* (i.e. - *...thought you wouldn't/didn't need to...*).

Snape is gloating over the fact that HP doesn't know what a *bezoar* is, and taunting him for having been so overconfident that he (HP) thought he didn't need to read/revise before this meeting.

Answer (score 2):

In effect this is a volitive, but it's nothing to do with volitive *will*.

"I think I will do such-and-such" is a conventional phrase for announcing an intention: *think* is softer than a flat "I intend to do such-and-such" and leaves room for someone to object or to suggest a better plan.

*Thought you would* translates this into the 2nd person and backshifts it into the past. Snape implies, sarcastically, that Harry made a deliberate choice not to prepare for the class:

> 'Ah, Potter, you looked at your book last night and said to yourself "I think I'll skip reading this assignment", eh?'

Comment: Isn't it just the past tense of *won't*- I *won't* do something now.  I *wouldn't* do something then.

Comment: @Jim Yes. Sorry for falling into jargon "backshift". And *won't* / *wouldn't* is perhaps more transparent than my *will* / *would* + *not*